# multidimensional tab in SonataAdminBundle

Tags: symfony, multidimensional-array, tabs, sonata-admin

I used SonataAdminBundle for a symfony project and I want to create a multidimensional tab in a EntityAdmin configureFormField function to populate a database table.

For the details I have a entity Domain with an Id and a Name, I have a entity Profil with an Id and a Name, and I have a entity ProfilDomain because I have three field (boolean type) display, modification, and deletion in other word this entity is a association table with the two previous entity with other field in it.

My question is How to display a multidimensional tab for populate this table in database like this picture[image: What I seek]

So is Sonata capable of doing this kind of tab with all the controller behind.

If not do you have some doc or some advice to do it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about a form view it looks like you can nest the *with* instruction. Take a look at the sources here: https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/master/Mapper/BaseGroupedMapper.php#L45

If you want to create such layout in a list view you can create a custom template for your admin. Take a look at the documentation here https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/templates.html

> If you wish, you can specify custom templates on a per Admin mapping
>   basis. Internally, the CRUDController fetches this information from
>   the Admin class instance, so you can specify the templates to use in
>   the Admin service definition

**UPDATE**

You can also define a parentAssociationMapping relation between two admin classes to gain deeper levels of editing.

In the parent Admin add this method:

```
public function configureSideMenu(MenuItemInterface $menu, $action, AdminInterface $childAdmin = null) {
    // ... compute $options
    $menu->addChild('TheChildAdminName', $options);
}
```

In the parent Admin configuration add this:

```
<call method="addChild">
    <argument type="service" id="your_child_admin_service_id" />
</call>
```

In the child Admin class add this property:

```
protected $parentAssociationMapping = 'theNameOfTheParentPropertyInTheChildEntity';
```

This way you'll have a side menu with all the configured child Admin

Comment: Thanks for your reply in fact it's on the form view. Right now the best I could I have done is to display a dropdown to select the profil, a dropdown to select the domain and all checkboxes to select with action is true.
My wish is to save several "relations" at once with this kind of tab.

Comment: I updated the answer, it's not your precise case but I hope it will be useful by the way

Comment: Thanks for your update but I don't have parent Property in Child Entity because I made relation like Many to One on the ProfilDomain entity with is the parent and I don't have property profilDomain in my entities profil and domain